# Using Custom Field to pull in image - if no img can the DIV not display? WordPress / php / CSS

Tags: php, html, if-statement

This is what I am using:

```
<div class="banner">
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner', true)) : ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner', true); ?>" />
<?php else : ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div>`
```

and..

```
#banner {
clear:both;
width:980px;
overflow: hidden;
background: #F4F5F6;
padding:12px 0;
margin: 0 0 15px 0;
-moz-border-radius:15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px; /* future proofing */
-khtml-border-radius:15px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}

#banner img {display: block; margin:0 auto;}
```

1. I don't want a title displayed so that if/else is not necessary.
2. If there is no img / the custom field is not being used, can the div just not show?  Right now if the custom field is not being used it is still showing an empty div.

SOLVED IT!!! Sorry for even posting here. Though it's not pretty, it works.

```
<div id="bannerHolder">
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner', true)) : ?>
<div id="banner">
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner', true); ?>" />
</div><!--banner-->
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div><!--bannerholder-->
```

Comment: The empty <?php else : ?> is not required and can be removed in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put the if clause around the div, not inside:

```
<?php

if ($banner = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner', true))
{
    echo '<div class="banner">', $banner, '</div>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the **if** clause encapsulating the div element and remove the else part of the php sentence.

Example:

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner', true)) : ?>
    <div class="banner">
        <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner', true); ?>" />
    <div>
<?php endif; ?>
```